# Encrypt data traffic between c# and mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, ssl, encryption

I have a windows application in C#.Net which uses mysql database to store data. Mysql DB and windows application are on the same machine. I am working through a security audit for a system at my work and one of the requirements is to encrypt all traffic between C# and Mysql. I have already implemented openssl and the connection has now encrypted but I also need to encrypt the Data traffic between c# and mysql. For e.g when the insert query executes from c#, the packet software (echo mirage) shows clear text(whole insert query with data) may be the reason is my c# application is using hardcode queries instead of stored procedures. How can I encrypt the traffic?   Please help

Comment: What do you mean you've implemented OpenSSL?  If the connection between your C# instance and MySQL is encrypted with SSL/TLS e.g. you've got a certificate, then there is nothing further for you to do.

Comment: Yes the connection is encrypted with ssl certificate but the data is not encrypted.

Comment: You asked in your question "how can I encrypt the traffic?" - the answer is that it already is. If you executed this query over a network, the query would be fully encrypted and not visible to anyone else on the network.

Comment: But my hardcode mysql queries written in c# is visible and it is not encrypted. I have installed the software(echo mirage) and when some query executes from the c# application it is visible in the packet.

Comment: I need something like http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/11g/r2/prod/security/network_encrypt/ntwrkencrypt.htm  but for mysql

Comment: Seems "echo mirrage" hooks up before the data are encrypted (showing data before they go through SSL). So If you really use SSL with the MySQL, the traffic should encrypted (try to use tcpdump to see the real network traffic).

Comment: How is it possible (showing data before they go through ssl). First i connect the mysql through ssl then it runs the query so it goes though SSL. I followed this  article to use SSL in my .net windows application: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-ssl.html

Answer (score 0):

If one of your requirements is "to encrypt all traffic between C# and Mysql", then I would recommend setting the [`require_secure_transport`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_require_secure_transport) system variable (on your MySQL Server) to 1. This will prevent any insecure connections from being created at all.

You will also need to configure your MySQL Server to use SSL, as per [this tutorial](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-ssl.html) (which you referenced in the comments).

In your C# program, make sure you have `SslMode=Required` in your connection string. This will ensure that all traffic between C# and MySQL, including queries and responses, is encrypted (apart from a short plaintext handshake at the very beginning of a connection).

Once this is done, Echo Mirage (or any network packet capture tool) will not be able to read the plain text of queries on the wire.

Comment: I have set the variable require_secure_transport to off also SSLMode=Required in my connection string in c# but still it shows in plain text :(

Comment: Sorry i set require_secure_transport variable to on but still it shows plain text in echo mirage

Comment: Which process are you injecting into with Echo Mirage?

Comment: Mydotnetwindowsapplication.exe

Comment: It looks like Echo Mirage is able to intercept the network data _before_ it's encrypted, because it's injecting into the process. If you use a true network packet capture tool, such as Wireshark, or inject into mysqld.exe (which Echo Mirage can't decrypt), you won't be able to see the plaintext data. Injecting code into another process to read its private data is vastly different than sniffing the encrypted traffic on the wire. Your connection is encrypted and you are doing everything right.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right but that means some one can view my code and queries tables etc by injecting into my application process through echo mirage tool etc. Can i handle it?

Comment: If an attacker can run code on your system and inject code into your process, then your security is already completely compromised. See https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/rhalbheer/2011/06/16/ten-immutable-laws-of-security-version-2-0/. What is the threat model that you're trying to (or need to) defend against? Most commonly, it's an attacker passively sniffing traffic that's passing between two trusted systems. `SslMode=Required` will defend against that. If you need to defend against a MITM attack, you'll need `SslMode=VerifyCA`.

Comment: The scenario is simple: my application is install on client machine and i don't want some one to inject application process and see the queries, tables etc.  I can't control the security at client. Now can i handle that?

Comment: That's an extremely difficult problem to solve. For example, game publishers spend millions on preventing reverse engineering and still their games get cracked or pirated. If a dedicated attacker has access to your program, they will be able to reverse engineer it and extract your queries. One way to solve this is a completely different approach to the architecture: put all the queries and sensitive data in a _web service_ that the client program authenticates to with a user name and password. Then you just have to secure the API surface, which is much easier.

Comment: That would be a very lengthy process. Can i do something to stop injecting my application process at application level. Echo Mirage allows some process to inject including my application but it does not allow some process to inject giving error (Injection failed,  Access is denied)

Comment: This is beyond the scope of your original question (about encrypting data traffic between C# and MySQL); please open a new question about preventing DLL injection and reverse engineering.